# Missing chrony package in Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, amazon-ec2, chrony, packer

I am using HashiCorp Packer to build a new AWS AMI. I want to preinstall the NTP client Chrony (it's popular in our organization and it will get config support from people outside our team). But when I use the AMI and do

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y chrony
```

I get

```
Package 'chrony' has no installation candidate
```

with some other interest bits from the packer build log:

```
amazon-ebs: Reading package lists...
amazon-ebs: Building dependency tree...
amazon-ebs: Reading state information...
amazon-ebs: Package chrony is not available, but is referred to by another package.
amazon-ebs: This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
amazon-ebs: is only available from another source
```

Which is odd, I'm not touching the `/etc/apt/sources.list`. If I `cat` it from the packer environment it looks like (edited to remove Ubuntu inline comments):

```
amazon-ebs: deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
amazon-ebs: deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
amazon-ebs: deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
amazon-ebs: deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
amazon-ebs: deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
amazon-ebs: deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
amazon-ebs: deb http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
amazon-ebs: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
amazon-ebs: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
amazon-ebs: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Seems like that should be sufficient to find `chrony`? I have also confirmed that chrony is in the bionic distro, it has a package page here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/chrony .

Does apt have different rules for resolving dependencies when run from packer?

Comment: And the package is listed in `http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz`.  You didn't get any errors at all from the `apt-get update` command? I'm thinking it truncated file, or that you're on a non-amd64/i386 machine maybe?

Comment: I'm on an amd64 t2.micro. I don't think the file is truncated? Is apt sensitive to ending a sources.list with a newline?

Answer (score 0):

Your software sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` look OK, but to save time you can use apt to manually download chrony and then install it. Open the terminal and type:

```
apt download chrony
sudo apt install ./chrony_3.2-4ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb
```

If that doesn't work try installing chrony with these commands:

```
wget -c  http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/c/chrony/chrony_3.2-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./chrony_3.2-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to figure out this funky error as well. It may be different in your case, but we were running into an issue with some packages being unable to install until `cloud-init` had finished provisioning. This HCL2 code should do the trick if you run it before installing packages:

```
# Waiting for cloud-init --------------
provisioner "shell" {
  inline = [
    "/usr/bin/cloud-init status --wait"
  ]
}
```